# Vim - force new lines with auto format option

Tags: vim

I am using `vim` with auto-format option to break the text at 72 characters. If I do `:set fo?` I get `formatoption=tqa`.
Now the problem is that I can no longer insert a manual line break: if I write something, then hit enter and type something else, the line break is automatically removed. So I need to hit enter twice to start a new paragraph, leaving a blank line. How can I do something like this?
some text on this line
some other text on a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `w` flag as well. Then a paragraph is only considered to be continued in the following line if the line ends with trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work exactly how I want. I am sure I had already tried it but maybe I had mixed it with some other flag...

Comment: @minomic Happy to help! If you have flag `c` enabled as well it will only work for code comments, maybe that's what happened!

Comment: The problem was/is that if I already have a wrapped paragraph and I delete some characters from a line, I would like the characters from the following line to "be shifted" so that no too short line remains... I hope I explained myself well

Comment: EDIT - maybe I got it: it works fine if I edit a new file but not on old files. It may be that old files have "real" line breaks which prevent auto formatting? Sorry if I say something stupid but I am kind of a newbie with vim...